# SQL Where argument returning as numeric and not boolean

Tags: sql, boolean, arguments, where-clause

I'm new to sql and I've been encountering the error 
"argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type numeric" from the following code

```
select subject_no, subject_name, class_size from Subject
where (select AVG(mark) from Grades where mark > 75)
group by subject_no
order by subject_no asc
```

To assist in understanding the question what I am attempting to do is list subjects with an average mark less than 75

By my understanding though the where argument would be Boolean as the average mark from a class would be either above or below 60 and therefore true of false, any assistance in correcting my understanding is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited!**

Use a correlated sub-query to find subject's with avg(grade) < 75. No need for `GROUP BY` since no aggregate functions, use `DISTINCT` instead to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct subject_no, subject_name, class_size
from Subject s
where (select AVG(mark) from grades g
       where g.subject_no = s.subject_no) < 75
order by subject_no asc
```

Note, I assumed there's `subject_no` column in the `Grades` table too.

Answer (score 1):

First of ALL, the Return Value of (`select AVG(mark) from Grades where mark > 75`) is not Boolean as you mentioned. It is exactly AVG(mark) itself. so you can actually write like:

```
select 1+1 from dual and the return value is 2 or select 'hello world ' from dual
```

and the return value is exactly the String hello world.

So , if you want list subjects with an average mark less than 75. following statements of where should be more like:

```
mark<(select AVG(mark) from Grades where mark > 75)
```

this is going to return a value of Boolean.
However, your statement explaining your question is too hard to grasp :P
I guess a programmer needs a little more time to understand SQL when you are not 
too familiar at first. Good luck. If you could explain your question more accurate... its much easier to have a correct answer you are looking for.

Comment: I see, so the issue is that I'm not putting a condition to be checked against for the sub query?

Comment: Exactly. Your sub-query returns the value of the field you selected, its not the condition value you were actually wanted. SQL is scary at first to programmers who are not too familiar with , but as long as you put a little time to it with few simple tables, and you'll find it relatively easier than other languages. Good luck ,Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You have more errors in your query - you have to join the Grades table to Subject Table, move the condition outside the select statement (and change `>` to `<`), finally remove the `group by` clause:

```
select subject_no, subject_name, class_size from Subject
where (select AVG(mark) from Grades where Grades.subject_no = Subject.subject_no) < 75
order by subject_no asc
```

You should rewrite your select statement to this optimized form (additionally you get the average mark in the result set):

```
select subject_no, subject_name, class_size, avg_mark
from Subject s
join (select subject_no, AVG(mark) avg_mark
      from Grades
      group by subject_no
      having AVG(mark) < 75) g on g.subject_no = s.subject_no
order by subject_no asc
```